# How to optimize a nested for loop with filtering in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying to optimize a nested for-loop with filtering, the code looks like:

```
user_ids = ['A', 'B', 'C']

all_dict_1 = [
    {
       'id': 'all',
       'user_id': 'B',
    },
    {
       'id': 'foo',
       'user_id': 'B',
    },
    {
       'id': 'bar',
       'user_id': 'A',
    },
    {
       'id': 'bar',
       'user_id': 'D',
    },
]

all_dict_2 = [
    {
        'id': 'all',
        'percentage': 0.2,
    },
    {
        'id': 'foo',
        'percentage': 0.3,
    },
]


def _filter(dict_1, dict_2, user_ids):
    if str(dict_1['user_id']) in user_ids:

        if dict_2['id'] == 'all':
            dict_1['percentage'] = dict_2['percentage']
            return dict_1

        if dict_1['id'] == dict_2['id']:
            dict_1['percentage'] = dict_2['percentage']
            return dict_1

    return None


hits = [_filter(x, y, user_ids) for x in all_dict_1 for y in all_dict_2]

hits = [i for i in hits if i] # Removing None values
```

the `all_dict_1` list is particularly long (thousands of objects), so the function takes more than 1s to run

Are there any libraries or technics to make it quicker?

Comment: Btw I think I spot a mistake there, what if `dict_1['id'] == 'all'` and `dict_2['id'] != 'all'`? Is it supposed to happen, that `None` is being returned?

Comment: Searching lists is slow because it has to check each item sequentially.  Can `all_dict_1` be a set instead of a list?

Comment: @JohnGordon yes it can, do you think it would be faster?

Comment: Yes.  Try it and see for yourself.

Comment: @LeoE if `dict_2['id'] == 'all'` it should fall into the first `if`

Comment: I asked, what happens, if dict_1['id'] == 'all'`

Comment: It's difficult to optimize things properly without any information as to what the program is meant to do, or what the rest of the code looks like.

Answer (score 0):

The logic in your question can be reduced to the following list-comprehension, which should be slightly faster:

```
>>> hits = [{**x, 'percentage': y['percentage']} 
                for x in all_dict_1 for y in all_dict_2
                    if x['user_id'] in user_ids and 
                       (y['id'] == 'all' or x['id'] == y['id'])]
>>> hits
[{'id': 'all', 'user_id': 'B', 'percentage': 0.2},
 {'id': 'foo', 'user_id': 'B', 'percentage': 0.2},
 {'id': 'foo', 'user_id': 'B', 'percentage': 0.3},
 {'id': 'bar', 'user_id': 'A', 'percentage': 0.2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `user_ids` a `set` to speed up `item in user_ids` tests. Filter with this first, since it rejects entries that you don't have to process at all. Use `filter` to avoid repeated global name lookups.

```
user_ids = {'A', 'B', 'C'}
filtered_dict_1 = filter(
    lambda item, ids=user_ids: item['user_id'] in ids,
    all_dict_1
)
```

Change `all_dict_2` into an actual dict to allow O(1) access instead of O(n) scanning. When iterating over your entries to change them, directly access the required percentage or use an explicit default.

```
all_dict_2 = {
    'foo': 0.3,
}
def add_percentage(item, default=0.2, percentages=all_dict_2):
    item["percentage"] = percentages.get(item['id'], default)
    return item
```

Apply the transformation using `map` to avoid repeated lookups of your transformation function.

```
hits = list(map(add_percentage, filtered_dict_1))
```